# Roundcube can send email, but not displaying received messages

Tags: linux, email, imap, postfix, webmail

I recently installed Roundcube on Debian Linux. I am using Postfix and Courier IMAP as well. Installation was a breeze and I was quickly able to send an email from me@myserver.com to me@gmail.com. However, when I logged into gmail and replied, roundcube has not picked up the reply.  If I `ssh` into myserver.com and run `mutt` from the command line, the reply shows up just fine. The reply is in the file `/var/mail/me`.

I think my question is, how do I get roundcube to read `/var/mail/me`, or how do I properly deliver mail to `~/Maildir/new/`? Let me know if there is some other path I might need to look at instead.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer:

`sudo postconf -e "home_mailbox = Maildir/"'

Comment: +1 for bothering to come back and post a solution for our future reference!